# Spree_auth_devise: how to add create.js.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, spree-auth-devise

I have modal form to sign-in:

```
= form_for(Spree::User.new, :url => spree.create_new_session_path, :as => :spree_user, html:{id: 'log_in_user', :'data-type' => 'json'}, remote: true) do |f|
  = f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', :tabindex => 1, :placeholder => Spree.t(:email)
  = f.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control', :tabindex => 2, :placeholder => Spree.t(:password)
  = f.submit 'Submit', :tabindex => 3, :class => 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-blue'
```

and some js into my welcome.js

```
$("form#log_in_user, form#register_user").bind("ajax:success", function(event, xhr, settings) {
    $(this).parents('.modal').modal('hide');
  })
```

It works fine, but i want to reload partial 'login-bar'

I tried to create user_sessions/create.js.erb

```
alert('123');
$(".user-area").load("<%= j render partial: 'shared/login_bar' %>");
```

But it doesn't work. 
So i can't undestand how spree_auth_devise views works, where and how i can override them and add my own js.erb files. Any help?

By the way, [user_sessions_controller.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/lib/controllers/frontend/spree/user_sessions_controller.rb) part with format.js:

```
def create
  if spree_user_signed_in?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          flash[:success] = Spree.t(:logged_in_succesfully)
          redirect_back_or_default(after_sign_in_path_for(spree_current_user))
        }
        format.js {
          render :json => {:user => spree_current_user,
                           :ship_address => spree_current_user.ship_address,
                           :bill_address => spree_current_user.bill_address}.to_json
        }
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a file at `app/views/spree/user_sessions/create.js.erb`.

Add code,

```
$(".user-area").html('<%= j render partial: "spree/shared/login_bar" %>');
```

Comment: Are you sure to have `.user-area` class at you `login_bar` html parent ?

Comment: Yes. For testing i added alert('123'); before code, but no alert appears after ajax is posted.

Comment: alert('123') will not work as this js is not a part of DOM.
You can check for console.log('123') though to verify if this js is been called.
Or check logs to see if this file was rendered.

Comment: Checked for console.log('123') - nothing(

Comment: check your rails server log if `spree/user_sessions/create.js.erb` template was rendered in submit request.